# Excel - Is there a way to change direction of a formula result when result changes? Rather than it dropping out of the bottom of the cell for example?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

When a cell returns a result the visual change always has the 'old' data dropping down and 'new' data in the cell coming from the top. Is there a way to change the direction of movement?

It will look really good on the 'mock-up' I am building.

Thanks

Comment: That sounds neat. Perhaps this is a feature in Excel 2016. I've never seen a cell's value change have visual effects. What version are you using?

Comment: do you mind clarifying your question a bit? Are you talking about the visual "animation" that drops your formula out of your cell? Or is this a question about a formula... i.e. why is your question tagged as excel-formula?

Comment: It may be when the result cell is merged and larger that the visual effect takes place. Using Excel 2013. I tagged it as excel formula as the effects are only when the data in a cell changes depending on input data in another cell being changed, so a formula essentially.   Basically, when you amend input data and the formal runs on another cell with the output changing, the visual change happens as described - old data dropping out of the bottom of the cell and new coming from the top. Maybe try it with a merged cell as the result cell?

Comment: sorry, but I don't think this has anything to do with excel-formulas. you may want to try with excel-vba, but even then, I have never heard of anyone changing the visual effect within a cell.

Comment: @JNevill - He's talking about [this visual change, for example when changing a `Sum`](http://i.imgur.com/NlXALrh.gif). AFAIK it was introduced in 2016. Unfortunately I don't know if you'll be able to change this, even with VBA as this is probably way deep in the Excel code.